# TcpListener is connected

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I'm using C#.

I'm looking for the best way to know if any client connect to my server

i.e

```
TcpListener myServer = new TcpListener(port);
myServer.Start();
....
```

Now, after the user has connect i want to start receive but to check before if the user isn't closed the connection

```
If myServer Can Receive Then:
   myServer.StartReceive(...)
```

So what is the best way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: reading the documentation would be a good start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can I suggest sockets instead? Not the horrible `TcpListener`.

Comment: @Bauss, you recommend me to use Socket object instead TcpListener? if so, why?

Comment: Because the implementation of it is horrible. If you want to create some kind of serious server, then writing it with sockets is a far better choice.

Comment: @Bauss, like at the following example? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should go with an asynchronous socket instead - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Bauss, i'm implement your link, how i can check if any client is connected to my server?

Comment: When you get a socket back from `EndAccept` then it's connected. Additionally you can check the `Connected` property on the socket.